# Remove fireplace leave metal chimney on roof

Tags: roof, attic, chimney, woodstove, flue

I removed a wood-burning stove and cut through the double-lined metal chimney flue in the attic. In the short term I jammed some insulation in the metal liner and left the rest of the chimney with the existing cap (*see pic*) on the roof. The top has a removable cap like this (*duct tape was a short-term fix to stop airflow*):

**Can I just cap the top off and leave the bottom where I've cut it?**

Whatever I do needs to pass a home inspection because we are selling the house soon.

[image]

Comment: I'll just remove it and seal the roof the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cap it with a chase cover if its not functional, your local sheet metal shop can probably make one at a low cost, here's an example:

https://www.kmsheetmetal.com/shop/Chimney-Chase-Cover-p195969014

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have left the zero clearance box intact and taped it closed in the past. When I purchased my current home it had the same, but wood stoves are common here.

In some counties, possibly the entire state, the stove must be removed or replaced with one that meets current code.

So it may pass depending on local requirements.